# Get inputs values from 2 templates in Meteor js

Tags: javascript, templates, meteor, meteor-blaze, handlebarshelper

How do I get the values from webelements in a different template called as an handlebar in another template.

```
< template name="temp1">
   <input type="text" name="new">
   {{> temp2}}
</template>

< template name="temp2">
   <input type="text" name="new2">
</template>
```

temp1.js file

```
Template.temp1.events({
    'submit .formclass': function(event){
        var new1 = event.target.new1.value;
        var new2 = ho//how do I get the value since it is not on this same form
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the template's `find()` method. If that fails, you can always use jQuery to get the exact element.

```
Template.temp1.events({
    'submit .formclass': function(event, template){
        var new1 = template.find('[name=new1]').value;
        var new2 = template.find('[name=new2]').value;
    }
});
```